# Upload Images Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an upload images from one domain to another (CORS).

The code works perfectly on Localhost but when I try in a real domain I keep receiving this message at the Developer Console:

```
Invalid request
```

upload-file.js:

```
function upload() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('img', $('#profimg')[0].files[0]);
  $.ajax({
       url : 'https://example2.com/upload.php,
       type : 'POST',
       data : formData,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       crossDomain: true,
       success: function(h) {
         alert(h);
       }
});
}
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example1.com');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
    require 'c.upload.php';
    $tsUpload = new tsUpload();
    echo $tsUpload['response']; //It have to respond a message like Uploaded Image or Image cannot Upload, not the message that I receive on the developer console.
```

I tried everything, like changing headers, not sending data from the Ajax Function, changing from https to http, writing the code from-scratch, but I always get that message.

My question is What is the problem? Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you look at the request in dev tools, the network tab, and show us what the request and response look like?

Comment: Yes. I receive this: [Pasted](http://pasted.co/4ab98f5c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got the `Invalid request` that means the request can not be create, that error is occur before http create .The `$.ajax` has a `error()` callback also, you can add it and check the detail error message.

Buy the way, the page'url which you send the ajax is **http or https**

Comment: Well...I don't see anything more than that message in the Ajax Error.

Comment: Both pages are HTTPS. p.d: And I tried in localhost with HTTPS and works perfectly.

Comment: And yeah. Was that. Thank you for your help :)